# Camera does not contain a definition for ViewportPointToRay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make a script that can shoot stuff but this line isn't working. I've googled the issue and even unity says that this is correct

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class ShootGun_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject bullet;

    public float shootForce, upwardForce;
    
    public float timeBetweenShooting, spread, reloadTime, timeBetweenShots;
    public int magazineSize, bulletsPerTap;
    public bool allowButtonHold;
    
    int bulletsLeft, bulletsShot;
    
    public Rigidbody playerRb;
    public float recoilForce;
    
    bool shooting, readyToShoot, reloading;
    
    public Camera fpsCam;
    public Transform attackPoint;
    
    public GameObject muzzleFlash;
    public TextMeshProUGUI ammunitionDisplay;
    
    public bool allowInvoke = true;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        readyToShoot = true;
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        MyInput();
    
        if (ammunitionDisplay != null)
            ammunitionDisplay.SetText(bulletsLeft / bulletsPerTap + " / " + magazineSize / bulletsPerTap);
    }
    private void MyInput()
    {
        if (allowButtonHold) shooting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0);
        else shooting = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0);
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && bulletsLeft < magazineSize && !reloading) Reload();
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft <= 0) Reload();
    
        if (readyToShoot && shooting && !reloading && bulletsLeft > 0)
        {
            bulletsShot = 0;
    
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    
    private void Shoot()
    {
        readyToShoot = false;
    
**        Ray ray = fpsCam.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0));**
        RaycastHit hit;
    
        Vector3 targetPoint;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            targetPoint = hit.point;
        else
            targetPoint = ray.GetPoint(75);
    
        Vector3 directionWithoutSpread = targetPoint - attackPoint.position;
    
        float x = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
        float y = Random.Range(-spread, spread);
    
        Vector3 directionWithSpread = directionWithoutSpread + new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    
        GameObject currentBullet = Instantiate(bullet, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        currentBullet.transform.forward = directionWithSpread.normalized;
    
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(directionWithSpread.normalized * shootForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        currentBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(fpsCam.transform.up * upwardForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    
        if (muzzleFlash != null)
            Instantiate(muzzleFlash, attackPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    
        bulletsLeft--;
        bulletsShot++;
    
        if (allowInvoke)
        {
            Invoke("ResetShot", timeBetweenShooting);
            allowInvoke = false;
    
            playerRb.AddForce(-directionWithSpread.normalized * recoilForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    
        if (bulletsShot < bulletsPerTap && bulletsLeft > 0)
            Invoke("Shoot", timeBetweenShots);
    }
    private void ResetShot()
    {
        readyToShoot = true;
        allowInvoke = true;
    }
    
    private void Reload()
    {
        reloading = true;
        Invoke("ReloadFinished", reloadTime);
    }
    private void ReloadFinished()
    {
        bulletsLeft = magazineSize;
        reloading = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add your error in Question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you comment out the content of `Shoot` and put `Debug.Log(fpsCam.GetType());` into `Awake` .. I suspect you have your own type somewhere called `Camera`